# Find $det(BA)$ if $A$ and $B$ be matrices of order $3\times 2$ and $2\times 3$ respectively.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices of order $3\times 2$ and $2\times 3$ respectively. Suppose that their product 
$AB=\begin{bmatrix}         8 & 2  &-2\\         2 & 5  &4\\         -2 & 4  &5\\    \end{bmatrix}$ and $BA$ is non-singular, then find $det(BA)$

**My Attempt**

Considering the order of the given matrices according to established theory $det(AB)=0$.

But now how to find $det(BA)$

Comment: That determinant is zero.

Comment: I don't think it can be -16 as $ rank(AB) < 3 $

Comment: My mistake. I have edited. Please see now. I can't find way to proceed.

Comment: But this is only true if both $A$ and $B$ are square matrices

Comment: @whpowell96 Only for square matrices $A,B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most straightforward answer would be to use Cauchy-Binet or Newton's Identities.

if you don't know Newton's Identities, you can get to the same result here via Cayley Hamilton

$C:=BA$
per Cayley Hamilton
$C^2 - \text{trace}\big(C\big)C + \det\big(C\big)I_2 = \mathbf 0$
re-arranging terms
$ \det\big(C\big)I_2 = -C^2 + \text{trace}\big(C\big)C $
taking the trace and dividing by 2
$ \det\big(BA\big) = \det\big(C\big) = -\frac{1}{2}\text{trace}\big(C^2\big) + \frac{1}{2}\text{trace}\big(C\big)^2 $

to finish this off, via cyclic property of trace:
$\text{trace}\big(C\big) = \text{trace}\big(BA\big) = \text{trace}\big(AB\big)$
and
$\text{trace}\big(C^2\big) = \text{trace}\big((BA)^2\big)  = \text{trace}\big(BABA\big)= \text{trace}\big(ABAB\big) = \text{trace}\big((AB)^2\big)$

so to complete the the problem you need to sum the diagonal elements of $AB$ and of $(AB)^2$.

Computational note: you there's no need to compute all of $(AB)^2$, you just need to compute it's 3 diagonal elements via 3 dot product operations, then sum them to get $\text{trace}\big((AB)^2\big)$.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to avail yourself of the characteristic polynomial of the $3×3$ matrix and recognize that the nonzero eigenvalues of $BA$ will match those of $AB$ (including geometric multiplicities).  Thus:

$\det(AB-\lambda I)=-(\lambda^3-a_2\lambda^2+a_1\lambda-a_0)$

$a_2=$ trace of $AB$

$a_1=$ sum of $2×2$ determinants centered on main diagonal

$a_0=$ determinant of full matrix $AB$

By direct calculation $a_2=18, a_1=81$ and of course $a_0=0$.  Then with one eigenvalue at $0$ the product of the two nonzero eigenvalues is $a_1=81$ which is also the product of the same two nonzero eigenvalues that $BA$ shares with $AB$.  That product is in turn the determinant of $BA$ so

$\det(BA)=a_1=81$.

Comment: I like your answer. I think that you should emphasize at the beginning that the non-zero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ coincide.

Comment: Done.  Also the multiplicities match, which is relevant here.

Comment: I am only familiar with the matching of geometric multiplicities, which in this case is enough to conclude that the multiplicities match (since $A$ is symmetric and hence $9$ has geometric multiplicty 2). Anyhow, this is irrelevant since the multiplicities do not matter in this exercise.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ then it is not zero and hence it is a non-zero eigenvalue of $AB$. Therefore, $\lambda =9$. This shows that $9$ is the only eigenvalue of $BA$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$(AB)^2=9 AB$$

What can you say about $(BA)^3$?

Comment: How did you get $(AB)^2=9AB$

Comment: That's really neat! But how did you find it?

Comment: The eigenvalues are 0,9,9. There are only 2 possible choices for the minimal polynomial, either this or the characteristic one. So I checked if by chance $x^2-9x$ is the characteristic polynomial, and indeed is.

Comment: @TonyK just multiply $AB$ by itself and compare elements.  (I used a different method to attack this problem.)

Comment: @OscarLanzi: You are explaining how to _check_ it, not how to find it in the first place. But the comment from N.S. explains that clearly.